# What options do I have on Winforms Video playback using .net 2.0

Tags: c#

what options do I have for video playback in my .net c# windows application.

currently I am playing with  "Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback" but this has, if I am not mistaken, a pre-requirement that DirectX be loaded on the computer.
are there any other options?

UPDATE:

I am using winforms .net 2.

Comment: Any reason you are still using .NET 2.0?  It is pretty ancient and 3.5 SP1 gives you some pretty great features.

Comment: I develop in house applications for my company, and it appears that most people still have only .net 2 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what display technology you are using (WPF or WinForms), but take a look at the WPF MediaElement.  It abstracts everything for you and plays really well.

If you are using WinForms, you can still embed the WPF MediaElement inside the WinForms if it makes sense for you.